# Increase data in a column of a excel sheet using powershell code

Tags: powershell

I have an ID `"ABCD07-12-1222_1"` which I want to increase by one till 45 times.
For eg the next record in excel sheet should be:`"ABCD07-12-1222_2"` and so on.
The last record should be `"ABCD07-12-1222_45"` till the 45th row.

I am using this code but its not working.

```
$codeName = $currentCode
$finCode = $codeName + "_" + $i
$currentSheet.Cells.Item($trow,$currentCol).Value2 = $finCode

$shikher=$currentSheet.Range("C10","C45");
$currentSheet.Paste($shikher,$false);
```

Initially I am entering the data to the first row and column.
Row-10 and column-C in excel. And now I have to increase the code to Row-45 and same column-C by one  each time.

Comment: `for(;$trow -le 45;$trow++){ $currentSheet.Cells.Item($trow,$currentCol).Value2 = $finCode }`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen : I don't want to do it this way. I want that auto-fill property kind of thing which is there in VBscript.

Comment: This method is fine but it takes time alot. So I would prefer some other method.